# How do I find the Field Descriptor of an object in JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

When calling the GetFieldID method through the JNI environment variable, you are required to provide a Field Descriptor for the desired field. How do you find what the Field Descriptor for an object is?

Example:

```
jfieldID strField = env->GetFieldID(myClass, "example", "Ljava/lang/String;");
```

How would I determine that "Ljava/lang/String;" is the Field Descriptor for a String object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javap tool will tell you what the Field Descriptor for a class is. To use it, navigate to a directory with a compiled .class file for the object with a field to be accessed and run the following command:

```
javap -s -p MyClass
```

This command will print out all of field descriptors for the class.

In general, however, most (non-primative) descriptors are of the form "Lfully/qualified/name/of/MyClass;".

Answer (score 1):

The [JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432) describes how to translate a java type into a type string supported by JNI.  You will need to know the type before you get at the fieldId.